# MySQL - Display rows as columns (as simple as possible)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, wordpress

I've been having some trouble with the following for a couple of weeks. I've read all the tutorials and snippets I've found, but can't make this work.

I have the following table (wordpress database):

```
post_id  meta_key              meta_value
802      _billing_first_name   John
802      _billing_last_name    Johnson
802      _billing_first_name2  Jack
802      _billing_last_name2   Jackson
802      _billing_first_name3  Jason
802      _billing_last_name3   Jasonson
803      _billing_first_name   Jamie
803      _billing_last_name    Jameson
803      _billing_first_name2  Oliver
803      _billing_last_name2   Olverson
```

I need a list of all persons from all the orders. The list should look like this.

```
ID    Firstname    Lastname
802   John         Johnson
802   Jack         Jackson
802   Jason        Jasonson
803   Jamie        Jameson
803   Oliver       Oliverson
```

Each order may have unlimited names. One order may be for 20 persons, while the next could be a single person.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use self join:

```
SELECT t1.post_id AS ID, t1.meta_value AS Firstname, t2.meta_value AS Lastname
FROM tab t1
JOIN tab t2
  ON t1.post_id = t2.post_id
 AND t1.meta_key LIKE '_billing_first_name%'
 AND t2.meta_key LIKE '_billing_last_name%'
 AND RIGHT(t1.meta_key, 3) = RIGHT(t2.meta_key,3);  -- up to 999 users
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/398866)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════╦═══════════╦══════════╗
║ ID  ║ FirstName ║ LastName ║
╠═════╬═══════════╬══════════╣
║ 802 ║ John      ║ Johnson  ║
║ 802 ║ Jack      ║ Jackson  ║
║ 802 ║ Jason     ║ Jasonson ║
║ 803 ║ Jamie     ║ Jameson  ║
║ 803 ║ Oliver    ║ Olverson ║
╚═════╩═══════════╩══════════╝
```

The point is `MySQL` is **relational database** and does not work well with `EAV` design. This solution may be slow in very big tables because join condition is `non-SARGable`.

**EDIT:**

I guess you want to join:

`_billing_first_name2` with `_billing_email002`

You can use to handle `000` with normal numbers, but performance will be poor:

```
SELECT t1.post_id AS ID, t1.meta_value AS Firstname, t2.meta_value AS Email
FROM tab t1
JOIN tab t2
  ON t1.post_id = t2.post_id
 AND t1.meta_key LIKE '_billing_first_name%'
 AND t2.meta_key LIKE '_billing_last_email%'     --email
 AND CONCAT(
      IF(SUBSTRING(t1.meta_key,-3,1) REGEXP '[0-9]',SUBSTRING(t1.meta_key,-3,1), '0'),
      IF(SUBSTRING(t1.meta_key,-2,1) REGEXP '[0-9]',SUBSTRING(t1.meta_key,-2,1), '0'),
      IF(SUBSTRING(t1.meta_key,-1,1) REGEXP '[0-9]',SUBSTRING(t1.meta_key,-1,1), '0')
        ) = 
      CONCAT(
      IF(SUBSTRING(t2.meta_key,-3,1) REGEXP '[0-9]',SUBSTRING(t2.meta_key,-3,1), '0'),
      IF(SUBSTRING(t2.meta_key,-2,1) REGEXP '[0-9]',SUBSTRING(t2.meta_key,-2,1), '0'),
      IF(SUBSTRING(t2.meta_key,-1,1) REGEXP '[0-9]',SUBSTRING(t2.meta_key,-1,1), '0')
        )
```

Comment: I like your solution, could you explain how you linked the first name and last name correctly. i.e Jack with Jackson and not Olverson. As you cannot use the ID as reference (and being hopefull the table is sorted correcly. I'm still trying to figure that out in my own query

Comment: @davejal Each key with EAV design has number, last `AND RIGHT(t1.meta_key, 3) = RIGHT(t2.meta_key,3);` do the job. Just "ne2" = "ne2", "ne3" = "ne3" ...

Comment: thanks for the follow up. I will have to look up eav design though

Comment: Thank you lad2025. Nice and simple code. What happens when we get more than 999 users. I.e. 200 orders with 5 users.

Comment: @Virik  It will work up to `_billing_first_name999`. For more you need to use `AND RIGHT(t1.meta_key, 4) = RIGHT(t2.meta_key,4);` if needed. Numbers of total records is not limited by that so you can have 100 users with 999 orders each

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. I forgot to mention... In addition to billing_first_name and billing_last_name. I also have 10 other fields. Would you still recommend this solution?

Comment: @Virik EAV in SQL world is not the best way(redundancy, lack of real relations, low performance and so on). You should read about [database normalization](http://www.phlonx.com/resources/nf3/) but it is very broad topic so if you want to redesign your solution you may ask new question

Comment: Thanks again. This is how WooCommerce stores it's orders, so I don't think we should alter the tables. We just need to present the orders in a more readable way.

Comment: Another question. Your code works because first_name and last_name has the same last characters, but fails at the field email. Is it possible to add leading zeros to the number. I.e. _billing_first_name000, _billing_first_nam002 etc.

Comment: @Virik Share samle email record

Comment: In addition to first and last name, I need the following fields: _billing_email, _billing_phone, _billing_date_of_birth, _billing_passport, _billing_divers_license, _billing_experience and _billing_logged_dives. If we could add leading zeros in the LIKE part of your code, it would work.

Comment: Thanks again. Seems like it's going to be a real heavy query. Should be better ways to do this I reckon. But it works :)